# How to set internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes in mongo db version 3.6.9

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a way we can set `internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes` in mongdb version 3.6.9 ? The admin command `db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes: newLimit})` is not supported in 3.6.9.
I got below error message

`"errmsg" : "attempted to set unrecognized parameter [internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes], use help:true to see options "`

How can we configure this for 3.6.9?

Related  - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-44869
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-44174

Answer (score 0):

Per the server ticket this feature requires 3.6.17 or newer server.

Comment: The limiting (SERVER-44174 $push and $addToSet should restrict memory usage) is also done on 3.6.17  - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-changelog/#id16 . But I get `"Command failed with error 146 (ExceededMemoryLimit): '$addToSet used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes'` error in 3.6.9 version

Comment: That is what I said.

Comment: You need to upgrade your server.

Comment: Upgraded and I was able to set the parameter, but when mongo shards got rebooted, the settings got reverted back to 100MB. How do we set this permanent ?

Comment: Use one of the other ways of setting it as described in documentation.